# how to convert string to float in csv file

Tags: python, flask

hello guys i want to convert a strings in some columns to float in my csv file , but i don't know how to do it explicitly , i have wrote some code but it's didn't work :

```
    with open(file_path, "rt") as csv_file:
        content = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=';')
        for row in content:
            values = []
            for column in row:
                values.append({'number_value': float(column)})
            payload = {
                'row': {'values': values}
            }

            response = prediction_client.predict(model_full_id, payload)
            print("Prediction results:")
            for result in response.payload:
                print("Predicted class name: {}".format(result.display_name))
                print("Predicted class score: {}".format(result.classification.score))
```

the row in my csv file :

$30,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm

the error is :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$  30,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if column.isdigit():
      column = float(column)
values.append({'number_value': column})
```

`isDigit()` will identify if the string is a digit or not.

You can then perform the conversion operation if the column is digit

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', "rt") as csv_file:
    content = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=';')
    for row in content:
        values = []
        for column in row[0].split(";"):
            if column.isdigit():
                column = float(column)
            values.append({'number_value': column})
        payload = {
            'row': {'values': values}
        }

print (values)
```

Output :

```
[{'number_value': '$30,000 - $39,999'}, {'number_value': 'RENTER'}, {'number_value': 'German'}, {'number_value': 'N'}, {'number_value': 1.0}, {'number_value': '25-29'}, {'number_value': 'German'}, {'number_value': '1 3RD PL UNIT 703'}, {'number_value': 'CA'}, {'number_value': 'LONG BEACH'}, {'number_value': 'LOS ANGELES'}, {'number_value': 90802.0}, {'number_value': '$7.00 - $7.99'}, {'number_value': '7Day'}, {'number_value': 'FM'}, {'number_value': 0.0}, {'number_value': 'CircAdm'}]
```

Comment: it gives me more error like this ====> TypeError: Cannot set google.protobuf.Value.number_value to '$  30,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm': '$  30,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm' has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: (<class 'float'>, <class 'numbers.Real'>) for field Value.number_value

Comment: i have updated your code. Can you check once. Also have put the output

Comment: it gives me this ====> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$  30,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm'

Comment: ah! looks like , the difference is in the ,csv file.The reason i see that error for you is because , the variable column is having the complete line as a string. It is not parsed the string with delimiter ';'



 this is the content of the csv file i have used. 

$30 ,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm

Comment: it is the same data , you provided in the questions. If you can share 2 or 3 lines of your data , i can check once more

Comment: i have just one row brother like yours ==>$30 ,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm

Comment: interesting! Can you print the 'column' content before isDigit() = []. This is to check if the column is being parsed properly. ideally you should get out put as

Comment: i printed out the colomn inside the for  loop , it contains that :==> $30 ,000 - $39,999;RENTER;German;N;1;25-29;German;1 3RD PL UNIT 703;CA;LONG BEACH;LOS ANGELES;90802;$7.00 - $7.99;7Day;FM;0;CircAdm

Comment: perfect! You see there , the string is still having ; in it. Means the csv delimiter is not parsing the columns by ;. 

Also it means , the complete data in your file is present in single cell of csv // something like this "<your data>".
check the new code above and let me know.
i have added "row[0].split(";")"  to split the content by ";"

Comment: now the error is ==>ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$30 ,000 - $39,999' , i see they are splited now

Comment: Are u using isdigit() to check if it is a digit?

Comment: yes i am using isdigit function !

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of Rows in your csv-file, may be the usage of Pandas is appropriate way for this task.

Here is example, how you can convert  "$30,000 - $39,999" to float like this "30000.0" , "39999.0" here is the code:

### read data from csv to DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = ';', header = None)
print(df)


Out[1]:

                  0        1       2  3   4      5       6                  7   \
0  $30,000 - $39,999  RENTER  German  N   1  25-29  German  1 3RD PL UNIT 703   

   8           9            10     11             12    13  14  15       16  
   CA  LONG BEACH  LOS ANGELES  90802  $7.00 - $7.99  7Day  FM   0  CircAdm
```

### processing data in DataFrame

```
df = pd.concat([df[df.columns[1:]], df[0].replace('[$|,]', value='', regex = True).str.split(r'[$-]', expand = True).astype(float).rename(columns = {0:'price1', 1: 'price2'})], axis = 1)
print(df)



Out[2]:

        1       2  3  4      5       6                  7   8           9  \
0  RENTER  German  N  1  25-29  German  1 3RD PL UNIT 703  CA  LONG BEACH   

            10     11             12    13  14  15       16   price1   price2  
   LOS ANGELES  90802  $7.00 - $7.99  7Day  FM   0  CircAdm  30000.0  39999.0  

# here it is become 'price1' and 'price2'
```

### save DataFrame to file

```
df.to_csv('test_out.csv')
```

Comment: i don't know how to do that with the code above , can you write this with my code, because i want to get a liste in payload variable if you can do that it will be amazing , because i am new in python :)